# tuning svm parameters in R (linear SVM kernel)

Tags: r, kernel, svm, libsvm

what is the difference between tune.svm() and best.svm().

When we tune the parameters of svm kernel, aren't we expected to always choose the best values for our model.

Pardon as i am new to R and machine learning.

I noticed that there was no linear kernel option in tuning svm. Is there a possibility to tune my svm using a linear kernel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [ETHZ](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-May/072069.html): *`best.svm()` is really just a wrapper for `tune.svm(...)$best.model`. The
help page for `tune()` will tell you more on the available options.*

Be sure to also go through the examples on the help page for `tune()`. `e1071::svm` offers linear, radial (the default), sigmoid and polynomial kernels, see `help(svm)`. For example, to use the linear kernel the function call has to include the argument `kernel = 'linear'`:

```
data(iris)
obj <- tune.svm(Species~., data = iris, 
                cost = 2^(2:8), 
                kernel = "linear")
```

If you are new to R and would like to train and cross validate SVM models you could also check the `caret` package and its `train` function which offers multiple [types of kernels](http://topepo.github.io/caret/Support_Vector_Machines.html). The whole 'topics' section on that site might be of interest, too.

Comment: I checked and theres no parameter for selection of kernel. It threw up an error for me

Comment: Which function threw the error? As in the example above, the kernel selection works in `tune.svm`.

Comment: think it was a typo. Its working fine now thanks a lot.